# Is there a way to get my missing month back in SQL

Tags: sql

My search results are missing January because my code calls for `year = year`. How can I get the January results in this search

I have tried adding `datepart` and without `datepart` to month_end_date = month_end_date

```
SELECT f.id
    ,f.bus#
    ,f.Mileage
    ,f.month_end_date
    ,f.Year
    ,f.Month
    ,f.Mileage - ISNULL(f2.Mileage, 0) AS diff
FROM dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f2 ON f2.bus# = f.bus#
WHERE (f.bus# = f2.bus#)
    AND (DATEPART(m, f.month_end_date) = DATEPART(m, f2.month_end_date) + 1)
    AND (f.Year = f2.Year)
```

The search should be bringing this line back for 01-01-13

```
id  month_end_date  month_start Bus Mileage fleet   Month   Year    bus#
92  2012-11-30  2012-12-01  Bus1801 33500   18462010    11  2012    1801
93  2012-12-31  2013-01-01  Bus1801 35480   18628718    12  2012    1801
```

But it skips the 01-01-13, because the year is different

```
id  bus#    Mileage month_end_date  Year    Month   diff
93  1801    35480   2012-12-31  2012    12  1980
95  1801    39436   2013-02-28  2013    2   2208
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Please [edit] your question to add that information and tag.    In MS-SQL you could use something like `DATEDIFF(m,f.month_end,f2.month_end) = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where I would use `datediff()`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW f LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW f2
     ON f2.bus# = f.bus# AND
        DATEDIFF(month, f2.month_end_date, f.month_end_date) = 1
```

However, `LAG()` is a better solution:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (f.Mileage -
        LAG(f2.Mileage, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY bus# ORDER BY month_end_date)
       ) as diff
FROM dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW f
```

Comment: I had to change it slightly, I cannot use LAG.   SELECT     f.id, f.bus#, f.Mileage, f.month_end_date, f.Year, f.Month, f.Mileage - ISNULL(f2.Mileage, 0) AS diff
FROM         dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f2 ON f2.bus# = f.bus#
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(m, f2.month_end_date, f.month_end_date) = 1)  Otherwise the first entry on each vehicle was the reading not the sum. Now it works perfectly. THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

If there was some sample data it would have been helpful but basically your left join is like inner join and would return only matching records as you have added in where condition. To avoid that you could use in this way.

```
SELECT f.id
,f.bus#
,f.Mileage
,f.month_end_date
,f.Year
,f.Month
,f.Mileage - ISNULL(f2.Mileage, 0) AS diff
FROM dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.NEWMILEAGEVIEW AS f2 ON f2.bus# = f.bus#
AND (DATEPART(m, f.month_end_date) = DATEPART(m, f2.month_end_date) + 1)
AND (f.Year = f2.Year)
```